# Is an empty evaluation stack required before an exception block?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

When I remove `Ldstr "a"` and `Call Console.WriteLine` (before `Ret`), the code runs fine, otherwise an `InvalidProgramException` is thrown upon invocation. Does this mean that an empty evaluation stack is required?

```
class Program
{
    delegate void Del();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DynamicMethod dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("", null, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator ilGen = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "a");

        ilGen.BeginExceptionBlock();
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "b");
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null));
        ilGen.BeginCatchBlock(typeof(Exception));
        ilGen.EndExceptionBlock();

        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null));
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        ((Del)dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Del))).Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect this is the case (that the evaluation stack must be empty before introducing a new exception frame) but I can't locate an official reference right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand what you're doing, I suggest you to make as minimal example as possible.

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "a");

ilGen.BeginExceptionBlock();
ilGen.BeginCatchBlock(typeof(Exception));
ilGen.EndExceptionBlock();

ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

After that, you can use `AssemblyBuilder` to dump the given code into the executable. If that's done, `ildasm` will show what has been generated.

```
// Code size       17 (0x11)
  .maxstack  2
  IL_0000:  ldstr      "a"
  .try
  {
    IL_0005:  leave      IL_000f
  }  // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.Exception 
  {
    IL_000a:  leave      IL_000f
  }  // end handler
  IL_000f:  pop
  IL_0010:  ret
```

As you can see, we will reach to the `leave` instruction which jumps to `pop`. You can then google about `leave`, which states that:

> The leave instruction is similar to the br instruction, but it can be
>   used to exit a try, filter, or catch block whereas the ordinary branch
>   instructions can only be used in such a block to transfer control
>   within it. **The leave instruction empties the evaluation stack** and
>   ensures that the appropriate surrounding finally blocks are executed.

However, why doesn't the following work then?

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "a");

ilGen.BeginExceptionBlock();
ilGen.BeginCatchBlock(typeof(Exception));
ilGen.EndExceptionBlock();

//ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I suspect it might not be "physical limit", but a verification issue. Let's run `peverify ourapp.exe` and see what we get:

```
[IL]: Error: [C:\temp\test.exe : Program::Main][offset 0x00000005] Attempt to en
ter a try block with nonempty stack.
1 Error(s) Verifying C:\temp\test.exe
```

At this point, you might be like, wat? With a little bit of googling, you can come up with an error code of **0x801318A9**. Quick scan through SSCLI2.0 sources:

```
case ReaderBaseNS::RGN_TRY:
    // Entering a try region, the evaluation stack is required to be empty.
    if (!m_readerStack->empty()) {
        BADCODE(MVER_E_TRY_N_EMPTY_STACK);                    
    }
    break;
```

Now, this is cool, but if you're geeky, you might wonder why does the evaluation stack has to be empty?

For that, you probably want to take a look at [ECMA C# and Common Language Infrastructure Standards](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa569283). I suspect you could find the reason from PartitionIII CIL.pdf

Comment: `peverify`, awesome!